Cython errors building Python bindings for OpenSplice CE 6.9 (Windows)
I am following the instructions to build and install the Windows python bindings for OpenSplice 6.9 and get a whole raft of errors in the listing below. Anyone any ideas what I'm doing wrong? I have installed "pip install cython==3.0.0" and Release.bat has been executed in the same terminal. Any help would be gratefully considered.
c:\VortexOpenSplice-6.9.181127OSS-HDE-x86_64.win-vs2017-installer\HDE\x86_64.win64\tools\python\src>python setup.py install
Executing idlpp
idlpp success
Compiling dds.pyx because it changed.
[1/1] Cythonizing dds.pyx
C:\Users\Graeme\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python312\site-packages\Cython\Compiler\Main.py:381: FutureWarning: 


Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...


# For each entity listener a global variable is used which is used
# to wrap the C listener and call the corresponding Python listener
cdef dds.dds_topiclistener_t topic_listener
topic_listener.on_inconsistent_topic = on_inconsistent_topic
                                       ^
------------------------------------------------------------

dds.pyx:1574:39: Cannot assign type 'void (dds_entity_t, dds_inconsistent_topic_status_t *) except * nogil' to 'on_inconsistent_topic_fnc' (alias of 'void (*)(dds_entity_t, dds_inconsistent_topic_status_t *) noexcept nogil'). Exception values are incompatible. Suggest adding 'noexcept' to the type of 'on_inconsistent_topic'.

Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...
# to wrap the C listener and call the corresponding Python listener
cdef dds.dds_topiclistener_t topic_listener
topic_listener.on_inconsistent_topic = on_inconsistent_topic

cdef dds.dds_writerlistener_t writer_listener
writer_listener.on_offered_deadline_missed = on_offered_deadline_missed
                                             ^
------------------------------------------------------------

dds.pyx:1577:45: Cannot assign type 'void (dds_entity_t, dds_offered_deadline_missed_status_t *) except * nogil' to 'on_offered_deadline_missed_fnc' (alias of 'void (*)(dds_entity_t, dds_offered_deadline_missed_status_t *) noexcept nogil'). Exception values are incompatible. Suggest adding 'noexcept' to the type of 'on_offered_deadline_missed'.

Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...
cdef dds.dds_topiclistener_t topic_listener
topic_listener.on_inconsistent_topic = on_inconsistent_topic

cdef dds.dds_writerlistener_t writer_listener
writer_listener.on_offered_deadline_missed = on_offered_deadline_missed
writer_listener.on_offered_incompatible_qos = on_offered_incompatible_qos
                                              ^
------------------------------------------------------------

dds.pyx:1578:46: Cannot assign type 'void (dds_entity_t, dds_offered_incompatible_qos_status_t *) except * nogil' to 'on_offered_incompatible_qos_fnc' (alias of 'void (*)(dds_entity_t, dds_offered_incompatible_qos_status_t *) noexcept nogil'). Exception values are incompatible. Suggest adding 'noexcept' to the type of 'on_offered_incompatible_qos'.

Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...
topic_listener.on_inconsistent_topic = on_inconsistent_topic

cdef dds.dds_writerlistener_t writer_listener
writer_listener.on_offered_deadline_missed = on_offered_deadline_missed
writer_listener.on_offered_incompatible_qos = on_offered_incompatible_qos
writer_listener.on_liveliness_lost = on_liveliness_lost
                                     ^
------------------------------------------------------------

dds.pyx:1579:37: Cannot assign type 'void (dds_entity_t, dds_liveliness_lost_status_t *) except * nogil' to 'on_liveliness_lost_fnc' (alias of 'void (*)(dds_entity_t, dds_liveliness_lost_status_t *) noexcept nogil'). Exception values are incompatible. Suggest adding 'noexcept' to the type of 'on_liveliness_lost'.

Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...

cdef dds.dds_writerlistener_t writer_listener
writer_listener.on_offered_deadline_missed = on_offered_deadline_missed
writer_listener.on_offered_incompatible_qos = on_offered_incompatible_qos
writer_listener.on_liveliness_lost = on_liveliness_lost
writer_listener.on_publication_matched = on_publication_matched
                                         ^
------------------------------------------------------------

dds.pyx:1580:41: Cannot assign type 'void (dds_entity_t, dds_publication_matched_status_t *) except * nogil' to 'on_publication_matched_fnc' (alias of 'void (*)(dds_entity_t, dds_publication_matched_status_t *) noexcept nogil'). Exception values are incompatible. Suggest adding 'noexcept' to the type of 'on_publication_matched'.

Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...
writer_listener.on_offered_incompatible_qos = on_offered_incompatible_qos
writer_listener.on_liveliness_lost = on_liveliness_lost
writer_listener.on_publication_matched = on_publication_matched

cdef dds.dds_readerlistener_t reader_listener
reader_listener.on_requested_deadline_missed = on_requested_deadline_missed
                                               ^
------------------------------------------------------------

dds.pyx:1583:47: Cannot assign type 'void (dds_entity_t, dds_requested_deadline_missed_status_t *) except * nogil' to 'on_requested_deadline_missed_fnc' (alias of 'void (*)(dds_entity_t, dds_requested_deadline_missed_status_t *) noexcept nogil'). Exception values are incompatible. Suggest adding 'noexcept' to the type of 'on_requested_deadline_missed'.

Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...
writer_listener.on_liveliness_lost = on_liveliness_lost
writer_listener.on_publication_matched = on_publication_matched

cdef dds.dds_readerlistener_t reader_listener
reader_listener.on_requested_deadline_missed = on_requested_deadline_missed
reader_listener.on_requested_incompatible_qos = on_requested_incompatible_qos
                                                ^
------------------------------------------------------------

dds.pyx:1584:48: Cannot assign type 'void (dds_entity_t, dds_requested_incompatible_qos_status_t *) except * nogil' to 'on_requested_incompatible_qos_fnc' (alias of 'void (*)(dds_entity_t, dds_requested_incompatible_qos_status_t *) noexcept nogil'). Exception values are incompatible. Suggest adding 'noexcept' to the type of 'on_requested_incompatible_qos'.

Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...
writer_listener.on_publication_matched = on_publication_matched

cdef dds.dds_readerlistener_t reader_listener
reader_listener.on_requested_deadline_missed = on_requested_deadline_missed
reader_listener.on_requested_incompatible_qos = on_requested_incompatible_qos
reader_listener.on_sample_rejected = on_sample_rejected
                                     ^
------------------------------------------------------------

dds.pyx:1585:37: Cannot assign type 'void (dds_entity_t, dds_sample_rejected_status_t *) except * nogil' to 'on_sample_rejected_fnc' (alias of 'void (*)(dds_entity_t, dds_sample_rejected_status_t *) noexcept nogil'). Exception values are incompatible. Suggest adding 'noexcept' to the type of 'on_sample_rejected'.

Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...

cdef dds.dds_readerlistener_t reader_listener
reader_listener.on_requested_deadline_missed = on_requested_deadline_missed
reader_listener.on_requested_incompatible_qos = on_requested_incompatible_qos
reader_listener.on_sample_rejected = on_sample_rejected
reader_listener.on_liveliness_changed = on_liveliness_changed
                                        ^
------------------------------------------------------------

dds.pyx:1586:40: Cannot assign type 'void (dds_entity_t, dds_liveliness_changed_status_t *) except * nogil' to 'on_liveliness_changed_fnc' (alias of 'void (*)(dds_entity_t, dds_liveliness_changed_status_t *) noexcept nogil'). Exception values are incompatible. Suggest adding 'noexcept' to the type of 'on_liveliness_changed'.

Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...
cdef dds.dds_readerlistener_t reader_listener
reader_listener.on_requested_deadline_missed = on_requested_deadline_missed
reader_listener.on_requested_incompatible_qos = on_requested_incompatible_qos
reader_listener.on_sample_rejected = on_sample_rejected
reader_listener.on_liveliness_changed = on_liveliness_changed
reader_listener.on_data_available = on_data_available
                                    ^
------------------------------------------------------------

dds.pyx:1587:36: Cannot assign type 'void (dds_entity_t) except * nogil' to 'on_data_available_fnc' (alias of 'void (*)(dds_entity_t) noexcept nogil'). Exception values are incompatible. Suggest adding 'noexcept' to the type of 'on_data_available'.

Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...
reader_listener.on_requested_deadline_missed = on_requested_deadline_missed
reader_listener.on_requested_incompatible_qos = on_requested_incompatible_qos
reader_listener.on_sample_rejected = on_sample_rejected
reader_listener.on_liveliness_changed = on_liveliness_changed
reader_listener.on_data_available = on_data_available
reader_listener.on_subscription_matched = on_subscription_matched
                                          ^
------------------------------------------------------------

dds.pyx:1588:42: Cannot assign type 'void (dds_entity_t, dds_subscription_matched_status_t *) except * nogil' to 'on_subscription_matched_fnc' (alias of 'void (*)(dds_entity_t, dds_subscription_matched_status_t *) noexcept nogil'). Exception values are incompatible. Suggest adding 'noexcept' to the type of 'on_subscription_matched'.

Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...
reader_listener.on_requested_incompatible_qos = on_requested_incompatible_qos
reader_listener.on_sample_rejected = on_sample_rejected
reader_listener.on_liveliness_changed = on_liveliness_changed
reader_listener.on_data_available = on_data_available
reader_listener.on_subscription_matched = on_subscription_matched
reader_listener.on_sample_lost = on_sample_lost
                                 ^
------------------------------------------------------------

dds.pyx:1589:33: Cannot assign type 'void (dds_entity_t, dds_sample_lost_status_t *) except * nogil' to 'on_sample_lost_fnc' (alias of 'void (*)(dds_entity_t, dds_sample_lost_status_t *) noexcept nogil'). Exception values are incompatible. Suggest adding 'noexcept' to the type of 'on_sample_lost'.

Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...
cdef dds.dds_publisherlistener_t publisher_listener
publisher_listener.writerlistener = writer_listener

cdef dds.dds_subscriberlistener_t subscriber_listener
subscriber_listener.readerlistener = reader_listener
subscriber_listener.on_data_readers = on_data_on_readers
                                      ^
------------------------------------------------------------

dds.pyx:1596:38: Cannot assign type 'void (dds_entity_t) except * nogil' to 'on_data_readers_fnc' (alias of 'void (*)(dds_entity_t) noexcept nogil'). Exception values are incompatible. Suggest adding 'noexcept' to the type of 'on_data_on_readers'.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\VortexOpenSplice-6.9.181127OSS-HDE-x86_64.win-vs2017-installer\HDE\x86_64.win64\tools\python\src\setup.py", line 68, in <module>
    extensions = cythonize(extensions)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Graeme\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python312\site-packages\Cython\Build\Dependencies.py", line 1154, in cythonize
    cythonize_one(*args)
  File "C:\Users\Graeme\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python312\site-packages\Cython\Build\Dependencies.py", line 1321, in cythonize_one
    raise CompileError(None, pyx_file)
Cython.Compiler.Errors.CompileError: dds.pyx

